# How should I store a user's LDAP password in a cookie?

Tags: php, encryption, cookies, passwords, hash

So I have this black box authentication method, handed down to me from the accounts people, which basically amounts to `ldap_bind($connection, $username, $password)`. But of course, I want my users to be able to log in for, say, 30 days at a time.

The *naive but insecure way* to handle this is to store the username and password in plaintext cookies, then validate these using my black box every time the user visits.

The *way that usually works but doesn't because of my black box* is to store the user's password in the database (or store it hashed?), and store the hashed version in the cookie, and then compare the values. This doesn't work here since my black box demands the actual password, not a hashed password.

My current thought is some kind of encryption (as opposed to hashing). But since this is obviously a common problem, I thought I'd best ask around first to see if there's a better solution lying around, or if not, what you would suggest for the encryption/decryption method.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This will not really answer your question, **but you should NOT store your users passwords, not even encrypted.**

If you really really have to do it, and the users understand that you are doing it. then store the password in a database of your application (encrypted, of course) and then send the user a cookie with a hash. When the user wants to login, compare the hash to what you stored and only then send the unencrypted password to the ldap. Never send the password (not even encrypted) to the user's machine.

Again, this is a very bad practice. if the ldap does not allow you store sessions/passwords then there is probably a good reason for this.

Comment: This is not so good, since I don't want to maintain a username/password database---that's LDAP's job. I just want to verify that the username/password combo that my users send me is indeed verified versus LDAP, and if so, let them stay logged in for some time.

Would encrypted passwords in the cookie be a huge security problem?

Comment: Unfortunetly encrypted password in cookies are a big security concern so you should not do it.
However, i think you misunderstood me. you will not validate username and password in your app. You will store the encrypted password+username and the hash of the password+username. Send the hash as cookie. Then, if the user is not logged in grab the cookie value, check the hash against the password/username and if all is well then send them to the ldap. Again, if the LDAP does not support automatic login that's about all that you can do. (or tell the users to user the browser's "save password"..)

Answer (score -1):

when the user logs in, give them a randomly generated "session cookie" (not strictly a session cookie because it will last longer than the browsing session) and store tuples of:

user_id | cookie_id

then hookup the cookie_id join the user_id with your user table and off you go.

Comment: What if the user is then let go. They then have a free cookie to login even though their ldap might not exist anymore.