# How to implement [save password] in the login page with spring security 3

Tags: spring-security

How to stored the login form's value in cookies with spring security 3.
Customer requiredment↓
If you checked the [save password] checkbox in login page and next time the password will fill automatically.

I think i must stored the checkbox value when authorizated successfully.
And next login time,If the cookie's flag is true,i will fill the password.
But i didn't konw how to code.Please help me ,Thank you very much.

Other question,I didn't add remember-me element in the xml file.
Why it can be remember me ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should talk to the customer.  Save password option is a bad idea from a web security perspective.

Spring security supports [remember-me](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/remember-me.html) authentication, which allows a user to visit an protected website if he has logged in earlier and has not logged out.  This it does by using a cookie, but not one containing the password.

Comment: I konw save pwd is not a good requiredment.But my boss required me attend to clients' needs

Comment: I want to konw whether or not remember-me is selectable.When i checked the box rember-me service is valid.otherwise,It's invalid.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Spring Security is not going to help you here. The remember me functionality in Spring Security is for auto login user and will not work to prefill password value in login form. You can customize a filter or loginSuccessHandler to add your own cookie. Please also see [How should I store a user's LDAP password in a cookie?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1737199/how-should-i-store-a-users-ldap-password-in-a-cookie) and similar posts on this site that recommend other ways to implement this instead of directly exposing password (even encrypted one) in a cookie.