# PHP LDAP session Persistence

Tags: php, ldap

I am working on a website in PHP with a simple user authentication and CRUD with a LDAP.
I have set rules in my AD to specify which groups can or cannot edit other groups and which attributes can edit users.

The problem is, after successfully binding the user to the AD and redirecting to another page, the session previously binded is gone.

Juste after the authentication and before the redirection, the function [ldap_exop_whoami()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-exop-whoami.php) returns me the DN of the user. But, after a redirection, it returns nothing.

I red on [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13422746/keep-ldap-session) that "*PHP LDAP doesn't support persistent connections.*" and this has been the **only** informations about this that i was able to find.

I need to keep the user session for user CRUD.

For example, if a user wants to edit it's password or it's first name, the [ldap_mod_replace()](https://secure.php.net/manual/fr/function.ldap-mod-replace.php) will return "*Insuficient access*" surely because without proper session, the ldap might have tried an anonymous bind.

Is it normal that i cannot create simple user CRUD because of this behavior ?

For now, i see 2 solutions which aren't really security friendly.

- The first would be to store user authentication informations and bind on each page.
- The second would be to log as an admin each time there is an update.
  This is also wrong for security reasons, and it bypass all the AD configuration concerning users editions.

Am i supposed to work with this behavior ? Maybe i should use a library or something ?
I'm a bit lost and all of my "solutions" aren't really good, so if anyone have a hint or an idea, i'll take it gladly.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not about LDAP, the problem is about HTTP.

HTTP is a stateless protocol whereas LDAP is a stateful protocol.

When you make a HTTP request, your PHP script is executed and terminated when the response is sent, which destroys what was created in the script (the same way a mysql connection is closed when a PHP script is terminated).

The difference is that in mysql, the notion of each user uses its own credential to operate the MySQL databases is not used, you generally set a database user which acts as the user to perform the operations.

In LDAP you want to change this behaviour because it is not secure, but ... it always was.

So like in MySQL (for example), you will have to use something like a singleton which initiates your LDAP connection at the start of each PHP script when you need to connect to the LDAP server. To do this, as you said, you have 2 solutions :

- Store the user credentials and use them to open the connection on each page
- Use a technical account to make the requests

The difference is that in LDAP Implementation there is mechanism which could allow the technical account to act as the user. And act as the user in the  meaning that the modifications will be credited to the user (for example, it will be the user which will be referenced in the `createdBy` operational attribute fo the entry the user will create)

Take a look on this document to see how to implement that behaviour :

http://php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-sasl-bind.php

and

https://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/sasl.html (Section `15.3. SASL Proxy Authorization`)

NOTE: You will need to check the LDAP implementation you use to see if this mechanism is supported.

Comment: Wow, that was a lot of useful informations, thank you !
Your solution is really interesting, I'll start digging into the doc and see what i can do with the SASL.
I'll come back with the result.

Comment: Or use a programming language / run-time environment with which you can implement a multi-threaded service using persistent LDAP connections owned by the user.